# Madden NFL 12 - instructions?

Tags: xbox-360, madden-12

Does anyone know of an actual useful and comprehensive list of the on-the-field controls for Madden NFL '12? A simple (but complete!) list of buttons and what they do would be rather nice.

The in-game manual is awful, and my google-fu is not helping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out GameFly's [list of controls](http://www.gamefly.com/game/xbox-360/Madden-NFL-12/146990/GameplayControls/) and see if that covers it for you: it seems comprehensive to me, but then I don't currently have the game running.

> **OFFENSE CONTROLS (PASSING)**
>
> <kbd>Ⓛ</kbd> Lead the Receiver
>
> click <kbd>Ⓡ</kbd> Throw Ball Away
>
> <kbd>Ⓐ</kbd> A receiver, Lob Pass (Tap)/ Bullet Pass (Hold)
>   <kbd>Ⓑ</kbd> B receiver, Lob Pass (Tap)/ Bullet Pass (Hold)
>   <kbd>Ⓧ</kbd> X receiver, Lob Pass (Tap)/ Bullet Pass (Hold)
>   <kbd>Ⓨ</kbd> Y receiver, Lob Pass (Tap)/ Bullet Pass (Hold)
>   <kbd>LB</kbd> LB receiver, Lob Pass (Tap)/ Bullet Pass (Hold)
>   <kbd>RB</kbd> Pump Fake
>   <kbd>RT</kbd> QB Scramble (Hold)
>
> **OFFENSE CONTROLS (RUSHING)**
>
> <kbd>Ⓐ</kbd> Stiff Arm
>   <kbd>Ⓑ</kbd> Spin
>   <kbd>Ⓧ</kbd> Dive (Hold)/QB Slide (Tap)
>   <kbd>Ⓨ</kbd> Jump/Hurdle
>   <kbd>RB</kbd> Protect Ball
>   <kbd>RT</kbd> Pitch Ball
>
> **DEFENSE PURSUIT CONTROLS**
>
> <kbd>Ⓐ</kbd> Defensive Assist
>   <kbd>Ⓑ</kbd> Switch Player
>   <kbd>Ⓧ</kbd> Dive
>   <kbd>Ⓨ</kbd> Jump
>   <kbd>LB</kbd> Strip Ball
>   <kbd>LT</kbd> Strafe
>
> **DEFENSE ENGAGED CONTROLS**
>
> <kbd>Ⓡ</kbd> Left/Right = Finesse Move, Down = Power Move
>   <kbd>Ⓑ</kbd> Switch Player
>   <kbd>Ⓨ</kbd> Hands Up/Bat
>
> **OFFENSE CONTROLS (AT LINE OF SCRIMMAGE)**
>
> <kbd>Ⓐ</kbd> Snap Ball
>   <kbd>Ⓧ</kbd> Call Audible
>   <kbd>RB</kbd> Fake Snap
>   <kbd>Ⓡ</kbd> Left/Right = Switch Direction of a Running Play
>
> click <kbd>Ⓛ</kbd> Quiet Crowd
>   click <kbd>Ⓡ</kbd> Pre-Play Menu:
>
> d-pad <kbd>↑</kbd>, then <kbd>Ⓡ</kbd> or d-pad: Call a Hot Route
>
> <kbd>Ⓑ</kbd>, then <kbd>Ⓛ</kbd> or d-pad <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd>: Send Player in Motion
>
> click <kbd>Ⓡ</kbd>, then d-pad <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd>: Line Shifts
>
> **DEFENSE CONTROLS (PREPLAY)**
>
> <kbd>Ⓐ</kbd> or <kbd>Ⓑ</kbd> + <kbd>Ⓛ</kbd> or d-pad: Switch Players
>
> click <kbd>Ⓛ</kbd> Pump Up Crowd
>   click <kbd>Ⓡ</kbd> Pre-Play Menu:
>
> <kbd>Ⓧ</kbd> Call Audible
>   <kbd>LT</kbd> Show Player Play Art
>   <kbd>RT</kbd> Show Play Art
>
> **SPECIAL TEAMS CONTROLS**
>
> <kbd>Ⓐ</kbd> Start Kick Meter, Kick Power, Kick Accuracy
>   <kbd>Ⓑ</kbd> Onside Kick
>   <kbd>Ⓨ</kbd> Fair Catch

Comment: This is missing controls for when you turn off some features, such as Auto-Sprint. I have sprint on the right trigger, but I probably customized it.